# Give element id numbers then insert one at end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an always changing number of divs and I need a specific div to go at the very end....
I'd like to somehow count the number of divs using javascript or jquery, and insert a specific div at the very end...
for example

```
<div class="message" id="1">

<div class="message" id="2">....

<div class="message" id="88">
```

Then I need the final div number and add one to it so it gets inserted at very end

```
<div class="message" id="89">
```

How would this be accomplished?

Comment: how do you generate the each div ?

Comment: Each div is generated through input in to an external file therefore you can't just place the final div at the end because new content will be input and thus it won't be the fianl div

Comment: Why do you have these? IDs containing numbers are usually a sign of something that should be using classes, arrays, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lastID = $('div.message').last().attr('id');
$('div.message').last().parent().append('<div class="message" id="' + lastID + 1 + '">');
```

Comment: hmmm... would this make the 'final' div at the bottom of the file?

Comment: I'm not really sure how the divs are being generated, but whatever content the last div needs could be put in the .append() parameter

Comment: each div is in a class called 'message', input in to an external php file through fwrite.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newId = parseInt($(".message").last().attr('id')) + 1;
$(".message").last().after($("<div></div>").attr({'id' : newId, 'class' : 'message'}));
```

with these lines you'll create a new div with 'max id' incremented by 1

P.S. it doesn't matter where the div are inserted, the new message will be inserted EVERY TIME after the last one